# Visual Studio Code Snippet Literal Replacement Ends Prematurely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets, literals, replace

When inserting a custom HTML code snippet into an MVC view, editing of the literal replacement ends when I begin typing a value.

Am I missing something?

My literal is used twice to replace a property name:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
        <Title>MVC Field Pair</Title>
        <Shortcut>mvcfieldpair</Shortcut>
        <Description>Inserts an MVC label/input pair</Description> 
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType> 
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal Editable="true">
                <ID>property</ID>
                <ToolTip>Model property</ToolTip>
                <Default>myProperty</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="html">
            <![CDATA[
                <li>
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m$property$) %>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m$property$) %>
                </li>
            $end$]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the XML is valid per [schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171418.aspx). I've practiced with the built in snippets, which also use a literal more than once, but those are for C#, XSLT, etc.

Could it be that IntelliSense is bugging out because I'm typing `.PropertyName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position relative to `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` is important. I adjusted my snippet:

```xml
<CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
        <Title>MVC Field Pair</Title>
        <Shortcut>mvcfieldpair</Shortcut>
        <Description>Inserts an MVC label/input pair</Description> 
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType> 
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>property</ID>
                <ToolTip>Model property</ToolTip>
                <Default>myProperty</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="html"><![CDATA[<li>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m$property$) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m$property$) %>
</li>$end$]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```